# Can Sources become Witchers?

Tags: magic, the-witcher

Theoretically, could a Source go through the process that creates witchers, survive, and retain their full magical potential? If so, could it actually increase their magical potential?

Are there any instances or mentions of anything relating to this in canon? (Books or games)

Comment: Hmm, there's possibility that Vilgefortz could have been sth similar, but it's speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Canon states, I think, that Geralt is one of a kind. There are no other witchers like him, and there won't be, as the process that created him was very dangerous and involved magic. And magic-wielders generally found him very annoying, dangerous and ugly. So we will never know what source-witcher **(Geralt class)** would be like...

Comment: *"Canon states, I think"* is quite disturbing ^^

Comment: I know, right?
However, I do not know if games are part of the canon (Author says the games pick up story where books left it, but I've read nothing resembling his imprimatur), so that's the second part (I think). I do remember all books pretty well - few of very small number of books in last two decades I've read in language they were written (and not being English), but games elude me... Want to play them first.

Comment: I read a quote the other day where Sapkowski said the games aren't canon to the books, but I tend to think of them as being a canon unto themselves.

Comment: Canon says that there were no new witchers but there were old ones, Geralt got additional mutations so he could have been unique but it is not connected with the question.

Comment: Yes it is, Geralt is a mutant from his childhood experimentation-on-by-magi. And only one living through the experience. Witcher is simply better trained, equipped and educated hunter. Waaaay better, but stil nothing unhuman. Case in point: Ciri, being a Source, received only witcher training. And look what it made out of her.

Comment: -1 You're simply wrong - Ciri is only person known for sure who got training without being mutated.

Comment: Yes, she's unique that way. However, we don't know for sure that every witcher was mutated. Everything that's said about them is that they WERE mutated (among other things). But they aren't now - and nothing says that Trial of the Grasses is mutating process, IIRC only one still administerable. "BOTE" states clearly: "They want to mutate the kid, undergo Trial of the Grasses AND changes." (My own translation from the original). Yes, they have THE eyes and magic can be felt on them, but DEFINITELY only Geralt is mutated. Maybe Vesemir too (basic mutation; he's OLD), but it's not stated as well.

Comment: Huh? The Witchers' whole thing is that they're mutated to become superhuman, and then trained in signs, alchemy, and a form of swordfighting that complements their abilities. Their mutations are also the reason they're despised, and because 6-7/10 die, the reason that there weren't a lot of Witchers, even before their ranks were thinned.

Comment: You see, that's the problem: nowhere it says they were mutated to become superhuman. Definitely: they were undergoing several Trials. One known is Trial of grasses, which changes shape of the eyes, gives them enhanced senses and maybe something else (other trials were ever mentioned in the movie, thus somewhat non-canonical). It's implied it was Magic, not mutation. That in witchers was ever said about  Geralt only (white hair). And AFAIK this is Authors intent. Also, they weren't thinned - they were exterminated, Kaer Morhen Keep was attacked and destroyed on purpose of ending "witcher kind".

Comment: Oh, and: they were despised because they were witchers. That is: they propagated by kidnapping children, they drank blood of the virgins, they were ruinuously expensive, they poisoned crops, raped and/or getting girls pregnant, They were charlatans, cheap tricksters and they were causing all the "monsters" to appear so they could "kill" them, They were thieves, murderers, highwaymen, they were hexing people and of course - above all else - real witchers were a myth and those who said they were them lied. And monsters don't exist either. All not in any particular order...

Comment: If they were exterminated, then Geralt, Vesemir, and the other few Witchers would be dead.

Comment: @WinterKnight: Oh, please. After they're gone, there will be no more witchers. So yes, witchers were exterminated. That few... that a handful is still alive does not change anything about the fate of their folk.

Answer (score 0):

"Can Sources become Witchers?"

### Probably, but no one would try.

First, we need to understand what "Source" is: it is a person with a wild, usually mediumistic powers:

> A Source,” she explained coldly, “has no control over their skills, no command over them. They are a medium, something like a transmitter. Unknowingly they get in touch with energy, unknowingly they convert it. And when they try to control it, when they strain trying to form the Signs perhaps, nothing comes of it. And nothing will come of it, not just after hundreds of attempts but after thousands. It is one characteristic of a Source. Then, one day, a moment comes when the Source does not exert itself, does not strain, is daydreaming or thinking about cabbage and sausages, playing dice, enjoying themselves in bed with a partner, picking their nose . . . and suddenly something happens. A house goes up in flames. Or sometimes, half a town goes up. <sup>Blood of the elves</sup>

And uncontrolled powers are indeed dangerous thing:

> Uncontrolled powers are an ominous thing. For both the Source and those in their vicinity. The Source can threaten those around them in many ways. But they threaten themselves in only one. Mental illness. Usually catatonia. <sup>Ibid</sup>

So can source become a witcher? Well, it is like asking "can someone prone to seizures and fits of insanity join the Navy Seals": even when 99% of the time that person is fine, there can be moments when he/she is not in control and then people will die.

There are no examples of source-witchers and most probably no one even tried: the trials and changes that witcher has to go through, would probably even more destabilise the child. Instead, wizards try to contain the sources, so to give them (both the source itself and the other wizards) a fighting chance to control those wild powers.

---

Just to add a comment to the previous reply: Geral was not a Source. Instead, he was a son of an enchantress, something that is indeed quite rare, because they are usually barren. Probably this gave him the unusual good tolerance to all of the mutations that he went through.